# Sharp gaussian in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

When trying to plot a sharp Gaussian (a*exp(-(x-b)^2/c) with c<3e-2) gives the following error

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}).

    ! Dimension too large.
\pgfmathfloatexp@@ ...}\pgf@xa =\pgfmathresult pt 
                                                \pgf@xa =0.434294481\pgf@x...
l.14    };
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [no marks, samples = 2000]
        {1 * exp(-(x-2)^2/2e-3) + 
         1 * exp(-(x-1)^2/2e-3) 
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to allow sharper gausians?

It works fine for values c>= 3e-2:

[image]

Comment: When you have gnuplot available you could use `\addplot [...] gnuplot {...};` to make it work.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Cool stuff, that and escaping the shell did the trick. Could you turn it into an answer? Also, out of curiosity, as I thought pgfplots always used gnuplot. What is the difference between having the `gnuplot` and not having it?

Comment: @StefanPinnow It's also amazingly many times faster, thanks  a lot ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433012/sharp-gaussian-in-pgfplot#comment1085291_433012) you can use `gnuplot` (if available) to do the calculations. Use an `id` to give the file that is used to call gnuplot (`.gnuplot`) and the export file from gnuplot containing the table with the data (`.table`) a useful name.

By default TeX is the calculation engine which of course is quite slow and not very precise compared to a tool designed for such calculations.

(And just for "completeness": If you use `compat=1.12` or higher *and* compile with LuaLaTeX the chance is high that Lua is used to do the calculations. Because this a bit off-topic in this questions, please have a look at [chapter 6 of the PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=527) on page 527ff in v1.16 for more details.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [no marks, samples = 2000] gnuplot [id=gaussian]
            {1 * exp(-(x-2)^2/2e-3) + 1 * exp(-(x-1)^2/2e-3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Why do you have the `id=gaussian` phrase?

Comment: See the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: I'm aparrantly really bad at reading ;-( thanks again ;-)